# How to modify a struct element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm working on a program that keeps a registry of pets in a hotel (homework exercise). I'm using vectors for holding the struct elements (pets). The code for the struct is this:

```
struct Pets{
string Name;
string Race;
string Owner;
int Tel;
}p;
```

And the function to ask for user input is this:

```
AddPet(vector<Pets> &vtnew)
{
Pets newpet;
cout << "Enter the pet's name: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Name;
cout << "Enter the pet's race: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Race;
cout << "Enter the owner's name: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Owner;
cout << "Enter the owner's telephone number: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Tel;
vtnew.push_back(newpet);
}
```

Ok, now I need to create a function to modify the pet by entering the name. I have a function that removes the pets, it is something like this:

```
void RemovePet(vector<Pets> &pet, std::string nombre){
pet.erase(
    std::remove_if(pet.begin(), pet.end(), [&](Pets const & pet) {
    return pet.Name == name;
}),
    pet.end());
}
```

Is there a similar way to modify an element?

Comment: Modify *which* element? The one you just pushed? And seriously, C++ is complex enough to read; try naming your collection and your lambda enumeration parameter *something* different. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: [Here's the question where a user created AddPet for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041926/create-an-array-that-holds-struct-objects-c). And [here's the question where I created RemovePet for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062126/how-to-remove-a-struct-element-from-a-vector). Are you planning on doing any of your work yourself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
void ModifyPet(vector<Pets> &pet, std::string name, std::string new_name) {
    vector<Pets>::iterator it;
    for (it = pet.begin(); it != pet.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->Name == name)
        {
            it->Name = new_name;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should realize that it's idiomatic and also better to use `find_if` which is available in the standard library exactly for this and reinventing the wheel, generally, shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
auto iter = std::find_if(pet.begin(), pet.end(),
                        [&](Pets const & pet) {return pet.Name == name;});
if ( iter != pet.end() )
{
   // Modify the object
}
```

Suggested improvements to code.

1. Use `Pet` instead of `Pets` for the name of the `struct`.
2. Use the variable `pets` or `petList` instead of `pet` for the `std::vector` of pets.

Comment: Incomplete answer, why would you stop there and not mention how to actually modify the object?

Comment: @nobism, the OP did not indicate which aspect of an object they wish to modify. I take it that they know how to modify an object.

Comment: It is worth pointing out here that iter is an iterator type, which handles the dereference operator and therefore also acts as a pointer of the object type, here `Pets`.  You can access and assign field values like it was just a pointer, like `iter->Name`